WriteString and ReadString in server and client in golang
I am implementing a simple server that can read the message send by the client one line at a time and prepend the line count to each line.
Here's my server.go file:
package main
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "net"
import "os"
import "strconv"

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Launching server...")
    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":12008")
    conn, _ := ln.Accept()
    defer ln.Close()
    defer conn.Close()

    outputFile, errOutput := os.Create("whatever.txt")
    check(errOutput)
    defer outputFile.Close()

    filewriter := bufio.NewWriter(outputFile)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    length, errr := reader.ReadString('\n')
    check(errr)
    fmt.Printf("Upload file size: %s", length)
    i:=1
    for{
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        filewriter.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i)+" "+line+"\n")
        i++
    }
    filewriter.Flush()
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
    fileStat,e := outputFile.Stat()
    check(e)
    fmt.Printf("Output file size: %s\n", fileStat.Size())
    newline := fmt.Sprintf("%s bytes received, %d bytes file generated\n", length,fileStat.Size())
    _, errw := writer.WriteString(newline)
    check(errw)
    writer.Flush()
}

In the for loop, it reads the message with reader.ReadString() one line at a time until the error(no more line to read) is null. When I run the code, it was stuck here, it seems that the for loop didn’t break as I am expecting, so I guess here is where the problem occur, but I don't know how to fix it.
Here's my client.go:
package main
import "fmt"
import "os"
import "bufio"
import "net"
import "strconv"

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
func main() {
    conn, errc := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:12008")
    check(errc)
    defer conn.Close()
    inputFileName:=""
    fmt.Printf("Input filename: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &inputFileName)
    inputFile,errInput:= os.Open(inputFileName)
    check(errInput)
    defer inputFile.Close()
    inputstat,err:=inputFile.Stat()
    check(err)

    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
    fmt.Printf("Send the file size first: %d \n", inputstat.Size())
    _, errw := writer.WriteString(strconv.FormatInt(inputstat.Size(), 10)+"\n")
    check(errw)

    fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(inputFile)
    for fileScanner.Scan() {
        writer.WriteString(fileScanner.Text()+"\n")
    }
    writer.Flush()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    if scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf("Server replies: %s\n", scanner.Text())
    }
}

In my client, it reads the file one line at a time and send the line to the server. I guess the problem is not in the client part because it worked with the server my teacher implemented.
I want to know what's the problem with my server.go. Thanks!

What error are you expecting reader.ReadString to encounter? (client.go does not close the connection so you will not get an io.EOF). You could set a Deadline, but as the file size is being sent, I'd guess that you are supposed to continue reading until you have received that amount of data.

@Brits Thanks for reminding me that that for loop wouldn’t break.  But I have to read the line one by one send by the client until the end, how can I know when the client has send all the messages so that I can break the for loop?

You are getting the file length into length (as transmitted by the client), so track the number of bytes you have received and, after each ReadString check if you have received length bytes (remember to account for the \n's). Note: as this is homework we will try to point you in the right direction but will not, generally, just give you the answer.
